# How should I configure my multi-monitor setup on MATE?

Tags: xorg, mate-desktop, multi-monitor

I'm running the MATE desktop environment on two monitors on Debian using the NVidia proprietary driver.

I'm facing a problem where after logging in, panel widgets like the clock or the Workspace Switcher move to the left, so there's a large amount of space between the widgets and the right edge of the screen. It looks like this:

[image: Problem illustration]

I believe that this problem is related to the different resolutions of the two monitors (2560x1440 vs 1680x1050). The distance from the left edge of the screen to the right edge of the panel widget is exactly 1680 pixels.

To try to fix this, I added manual configuration to my xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier          "DP-1"
    Option              "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier          "DVI-I-1"
    Option              "Primary" "false"
EndSection
```

This seems to prevent my widgets from being moved, but after logging in, I got a message stating "Could not apply the stored configuration for the monitor", so I'm guessing something's weird here, too.

Is it a good idea to try to fix this in xorg.conf? Does that prevent me from configuring my displays via mate-display-properties? Is there a better way to fix this problem?

Comment: Is it preventing you from using mate-display-properties? Have you tried to?  Have you tried setting up the display via `nvidia-settings`?

Comment: `mate-display-properties` seems to work, at least while I'm logged in. For unknown reasons, it started leaving my widgets in the correct place, even if I remove my additions to xorg.conf. It looks like right now the only place these settings make a difference is in lightdm. Letting `nvidia-settings` write xorg.conf seems to fix the problems in the same way as my configuration.